# How to update active directory data from SharePoint 2010 application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, active-directory, user-profile-service

Is there any way by which we can directly update active directory data from SharePoint 2010 application?
Plz guide how to do this?

Regards

Comment: Are you looking for a development solution or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean how do you make the Profile Service able to sync in both directs (from AD and back to AD).

This is a pretty long and detailed process. Normally I would never just add links to an answer but I think in this case it's all that can be done.

- [Plan profile synchronization for SharePoint Server 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182925.aspx#section6)
- [Configure Connections and export data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx#Phase4)
- [Mapping User Profile Properties in SharePoint 2010 to LDAP Attributes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tehnoonr/archive/2010/11/22/mapping-user-profile-properties-in-sharepoint-2010-to-ldap-attributes.aspx)

[This book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735662088) also has information on the topic and has a lot of additional info on My Sites.